# C++: Regular expression with negative lookahead and ^ matches on macOS but not Linux

Tags: c++, regex, linux

Why would the same regular expression with a negative lookahead report a match on macOS (and Windows), but not Linux?

Here is the sample code in C++:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  std::regex rx("^(((?!(\\/|^)\\.).)*?)$");
  std::string input = "foo.bar";

  std::cout << std::regex_match(input, rx) << std::endl;
}
```

The result on macOS and Windows: `1`

The result on Linux (tried with GCC 11): `0`

This issue seems to stem from the negative lookahead `?!(\\/|^)`. Specifically, removing the `|^` resolves the issue so it is related to having a negative lookahead with `^`.

Tried to use `std::regex_match(input, rx, std::regex_constants::match_not_bol)` without luck.

Interestingly when the target string does not contain a `.`, the results are same again.

Finally, the same regular expression when run in JavaScript also matches on all platforms.

Some details about compiler versions used:

- macOS: `Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)`
- Linux: `g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0`
- Windows: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86`

Comment: What a strange pattern: the `.` char cannot be ``\`` at the same time, so the negative lookahead is equal to `(?!^)`, and the whole pattern does just `^(?!\.).*` (and [it works](https://ideone.com/Qlyqd0)). Note if you remove `|^` from your original pattern, you can just remove the lookahead as it renders useless after that.

Comment: Please provide details of compilers version, since I got inconsistency, but in different way then described by you: https://godbolt.org/z/Tv5E7PY47 (in my case got `0` for gcc and clang, but `1` for msvc).

Comment: Added information about compiler versions to the text. Btw I did not invent this pattern, it is the result of creating a regular expression using the https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch glob library with an input of "**" and trying to use that in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Only two libs come to mind when I think of cross-platform regex implementation.

First is Perl5 syntax reimplementation: https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2

Second is tiny lib which implements some subset of Python syntax: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-regex-c

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Different Operating Systems use different regular expression engines.

Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines languages table for row `POSIX C (C)`

C++ standard library provides a regular expression engine that is based on POSIX extended regular expression (ERE) syntax
Reference :- [POSIX Extended Regular Expression Syntax](https://OS.https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html)

`^` - character is used to match the start of a string in regular expressions, but in ERE syntax it also has a special meaning when used inside a group. In ERE syntax, the ^ character inside a group negates the character class that follows it, so in this case the ^ character inside the group (\/|^) negates the character class .. This causes the regular expression engine to match any character that is not a ., which is why the behavior is different when the target string contains a . character.

You need to remove the ^ character:

`std::regex rx("^(((?!(\\/|^)).)*?)$");`

Comment: Oh no, default C++ `std::regex` flavor is ECMAScript. And there are several regex flavors one can choose to use. Morever, POSIX regex does not support lookarounds at all.